# Python - looping through list of discrete bins and selecting rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with `columnA` with integer values that range between -3 and 89. 
I want to select all the rows with values in `columnA` between discrete 10 unit bins, e.g. 
-10 to 0
0 to 10 ...
80 to 90

I can produce a list of the number of rows in each bin like this:

```
pd.cut(DataFrame['columnA'], np.arange(-10, 100, 10), include_lowest=True, labels=False).value_counts().sort_index().to_list()
```

resulting in a list like this:

```
[505, 25000, 21, 393, 79232, 953000, 24121, 662, 50, 900]
```

Now if I want to examine all the rows in the first bin, I can select them like this:

```
DataFrame.sort_values('columnA', ascending=True).iloc[0:505]
```

**How can I write a function to select all the rows in bin N?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? I am assuming that your bins are of form [a, b[ (closed on the lower bound and open on the upper one.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(map(lambda x: int(x), (np.random.uniform(-3,89,1000))), columns=['ColumnA'])

def bin_func(df, N, col='ColumnA', xmin=-10, xmax=100, Nbins=10): 
    df_sorted = df.sort_values(col, ascending=True) 
    bins = np.arange(xmin, xmax, Nbins)
    if N > Nbins-1:
        return(pd.DataFrame())
    return(df_sorted[(df_sorted[col] >= bins[N]) & (df_sorted[col]<bins[N+1])])
```

Comment: I just edited it so that the parameters are now part of the function, in case you want to change the bins and ranges later on.

Comment: Sure, it is a way to filter in pandas, select all the rows which satisfy the condition. Check this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas

Answer (score 0):

use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [Series.cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
def get_bin(n):
     return df.groupby(df.index.isin([505, 25000, 21, 393, 79232, 953000, 24121, 662, 50, 900]).cumsum()).get_group(n)
```

this will divide your dataframe into groups called 0,1,2,3,4,5 ... n.You select using [groupby.get_group](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.get_group.html).

**Here is an example:**

```
print(df)
   a  b  c  d
0  0  1  1  x
1  0  1  5  y
2  0  1  5  x
3  0  1  0  y
4  1  1  5  x
5  0  1  4  y
6  1  0  1  x
7  1  1  3  y
8  0  1  2  x
9  0  0  0  y
```

---

```
groups=df.index.isin([2,4,7,9]).cumsum()
print(groups)
#array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4])
```

---

```
print(df.groupby(groups).get_group(0))
   a  b  c  d
0  0  1  1  x
1  0  1  5  y
```

Comment: `def get_bin(df, n):`  when n is 0, keyerror is 0. When n is 1, all rows are returned. When n is 2, keyerror is 2.

Comment: I said groups of 1 onwards, if you want from n you must delete the + 1

Comment: I have created an example to make the application clear. I may not have understood you well, excuse me. Could you show an example with the expected departure and thus be able to help you?

Comment: I have removed + 1 so that I can select from bin 0